# Is $F(x)/<f(x)>$ isomorphic to a subfield of the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $F$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

$F$ is a field. $F[x]$ denotes the ring which consists of all the polynomials with coefficients in $F$.  Suppose $f(x)\in F[x]$ and $f(x)$ is irreducible over $F$, $a$ is a zero of $f(x)$ in some extension field $E$ of $F$. $F(a)$ denote the smallest subfield of $E$ that contains both $F$ and $a$. It is well known that all such $F(a)$ is isomorphic to 
$F(x)/<f(x)>$, and all splitting fields of $f(x)$ over $F$ are isomorphic. I am quite curious that is it the case that $F(x)/<f(x)>$ is isomorphic to a subfield of  the splitting fields? Some enlightening would be very helpful!

Comment: You’re forgetting the assumption that $f$ is irreducible.

Comment: Thank you, editing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The splitting field $K$ of $f$ by definition contains a root $b$ of $f$ (actually all roots). Since $F(b)\cong F[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$, you’re done.